# How can I derive the general expression for AC bridge balance?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

For example in Maxwell's bridge, or any AC circuit bridge, we just balance the impedances like resistances in DC Wheatstone bridge.
How can I derive the general expression below?

**Z1/Z2=Z3/Z4**

For reference, here is where the formula is used but it isn't clear how we got the formula:
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-12/ac-bridge-circuits/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

The input resistance can be found:

$$\text{R}_\text{in}=\frac{\left(\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag1$$

Now, the input current is given by:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_\text{in}}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\left(\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag2$$

Now, the current $\text{I}_1$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}\tag3$$

Now, the current $\text{I}_2$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag4$$

So, we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{A}=\text{I}_1\cdot\text{R}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}\tag5$$
- $$\text{V}_\text{B}=\text{I}_2\cdot\text{R}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag6$$

So, we also get:

$$\text{V}_\text{A}-\text{V}_\text{B}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}-\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\right\}\tag7$$

---

Now, in order to do that you want you can, for example, use a [Wien bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_bridge).

Than you will need to  change to:

- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{\text{R}_5\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_x}}{\text{R}_5+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_x}}=\frac{\text{R}_5}{1+\text{R}_5\omega\text{C}_x\text{j}}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\text{R}_6+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\tag9$$
- $$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}=\hat{\text{u}}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\tag9$$

Where $\text{j}^2=-1$ and $\omega=2\pi\text{f}$.

So, you will get:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{A}}-\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{B}}=\hat{\text{u}}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}-\frac{\text{R}_6+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\frac{\text{R}_5}{1+\text{R}_5\omega\text{C}_x\text{j}}+\text{R}_6+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right\}\tag{11}$$

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AbdullahAlHussni You're welcome, I'm glad that I could be of any help.